# How can I prevent Vue template from reloading when loading a Laravel view

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I am quite new to Laravel and Vue and I'm currently building an app and trying to incorporate Vue to handle my sidebar navigation items.

Currently my sidebar is populating as expected from my view template.  Everything is working great and when I first launch my app, navigation item 0 is selected and highlighted.  However, when I click on any other navigation item, I can see the `active` class being added briefly to that item, but then the new Url loads and my vue template is getting reloaded making navigation item 0 once again active.

I would have thought that only my `@yeild( 'content' )` should be reloading and anything sitting in my main blade template should remain unchanged.

Which makes me think I have overlooked something somewhere or have something wrong.

**Main blade template:**

```
<body>

    <div class="main-wrapper">

        <!-- Header -->
        @include( 'layouts.header' )

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        @include( 'layouts.sidebar' )

        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div @auth class="content-wrapper" @else class="content-wrapper-no_sidebar" @endauth>

            <div class="container-fluid">

                <!-- Main content -->
                <section class="content">

                    @yield('content')

                </section><!-- /.content -->

            </div>

        </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    </div>
    ...

</body>
```

**layouts.sidebar:**

```
<div id="side_bar">

    @auth

        <aside class="left-sidebar">

            <nav>

                <side-bar></side-bar>

            </nav>

        </aside>

    @endauth

</div>
```

**SideMenu.vue (side-bar template file):**

```
<template>

        <div class="sidebar-menu">

            <a v-for="( item, index ) in items" class="side-nav-item" :class="{ active: item.active }" :href="item.Url" @click="toggleItem( index )">
                <i :class="item.Icon"></i><br>
                {{ item.Description }}
            </a>

        </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                items: [
                    {
                        active: false,
                        Description: 'Dashboard',
                        Icon: 'fas fa-tachometer-alt',
                        Url: '/home'
                    },
                    {
                        active: false,
                        Description: 'Test Cases',
                        Icon: 'fas fa-calendar-check',
                        Url: '/testcases'
                    },
                    {
                        active: false,
                        Description: 'Applications',
                        Icon: 'fab fa-windows',
                        Url: '/applications'
                    },
                    {
                        active: false,
                        Description: 'Testers',
                        Icon: 'fas fa-users',
                        Url: '/testers'
                    },
                    {
                        active: false,
                        Description: 'Modules',
                        Icon: 'fas fa-sitemap',
                        Url: '/categories'
                    }
                ],
                currentActiveIndex: 0,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            toggleItem( index ) {



                this.items[this.currentActiveIndex].active = false;
                this.items[index].active = true;
                this.currentActiveIndex = index;



            }


        },

        mounted() {



            this.items[this.currentActiveIndex].active = true;
            console.log( 'Sidebar Loaded' );



        }

    }
</script>
```

**app.js:**

```
Vue.component( 'side-bar', require( './components/SideMenu.vue' ) );


// Define new vue instances
const side_bar = new Vue({



    el: '#side_bar'



});
```

Comment: You can't. If you don't want the page to be reloaded, you'd have to load the content via ajax, rather than a standard GET request. Making a standard GET request to the server will always result in a page reload.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Is there a better way to handle this? I ventured down the Vue path so I could manipulate the active status on navigation items and easily add/remove CSS classes to accommodate visually.

Comment: Why not just add the classes using logic in your blade template?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example of what you mean.  I am a little new to Laravel sorry.